# Set multiple html tags with same structure to height of the next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage that has multiple elements with the same structure:

```
<img class="rollover" src="http://www.example.com/images/rollover.png"/>
<div class="text">
    <h3>Example 1</h3>
</div>

<img class="rollover" src="http://www.example.com/images/rollover.png"/>
<div class="text">
    <h1>Example 2</h1>
</div>
```

I want to set the height of the img tags with class="rollover" to the same height as the next div with class="text". There can be one or more of these appearing on the page. I have some basic jquery that can set the heights equal, but it sets all of the images to the same height. How can I adjust it so that it just takes the next div's height?

```
$('.rollover').height($('.text').height());
```

Comment: do you absolutely have to use a `class` for `text` or can you use an `id` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works if there are always corresponding imgs and text-divs as in your code shown.

```
var txt = $('.text');
$('.rollover').each(function(i) {$(this).height(txt.eq(i).height());});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var x = $(".rollover").length;
for(var i=1; i<=x; i++)
{
    var h = $(".rollover:nth-child('+i+'").next(".text").height();
    $(".rollover:nth-child('+i+').height(h);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is appearing in the low quality answers stack for review, perhaps you could add in a little text about why and how this answer works?

Answer (score 0):

You may put each pair of img and div inside a new div element. This will improve the readability of the code...

```
<div class="eaqualHeight">
  <img class="rollover" src="http://www.example.com/images/rollover.png"/>
  <div class="text">
    <h3>Example 1</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="eaqualHeight">
  <img class="rollover" src="http://www.example.com/images/rollover.png"/>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Example 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then use following jquery code...

```
$('.eaqualHeight').each(function(){
  $(this).children('.rollover').height($(this).children('.text').height());
});
```